# I'm using a Slack Bot account to call from my web app into the slack API. How long lived is a bot token?

Tags: slack-api

Everything is configured appropriately, but I can't find a definitive answer on how long lived the bot API token is. Can anyone confirm it's valid until a refresh request is submitted?

Comment: Have you tried asking the Slack help? They are pretty fast with their respone. Same goes for the @SlackAPI twitter account.

Answer (score 1):

I asked Slack (via Twitter) and the reply was that  the token for bots doesn't expire until a forced refresh.